# Software to block a website in windows

Tags: windows, windows-8, website-blocker

I need to block some websites in my PC. It is running on Windows 8. I tried to block the website by editing the 'host' file in Windows/System32/Drivers/etc folder. Unfortunately it didn't worked.

I don't prefer an antivirus software. I need a clean software that didn't show its name or other details when blocking a site. Can anyone recommend a good software for me ?

Comment: I use the hosts file as well.
Perhaps you might open a question on Super User and explain what you did, so someone can point out where you whent wrong.
I suggest making sure the web cache has been cleared on all browsers. (as that will give you a false, bipass)

Comment: Do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers! If you want a website blocker on Linux, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've helped a lab tech friend of mine setup [Focal Filter](http://www.focalfilter.com/) sometime back. I don't have much experience with it but from the homepage it seems to be pretty intuitive to use and configure.

[image]
[image]

- Free
- Blocks multiple sites
- Has a time delay
- Works across multiple versions of windows, Xp and up

There is also a list of other free alternatives at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend going without additional software. To edit your `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file, make sure you are running Notepad **As Administrator**.

If it still does not work, check the ownership of the file. I've already seen it set weird way. I've taken it, re-checked appropriate permissions and then editing worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend **[Cold Turkey](http://getcoldturkey.com/)**. Freeware and works with Windows 8, Windows 7, Vista and updated versions of Windows XP, 2000 and NT.

Features (quoting its website):

> - Block Sites - Use the default list of popular sites to block, or add any number of your own to the list.
> - Block Applications - Cold Turkey can block programs too! Just browse to the executable file to add it to the list.
> - Computer Wide - Cold Turkey's blocking features are computer-wide, which will affect all users and browsers on the computer.
> - Schedule your Block - Cold Turkey can be scheduled to block you in intervals of a half an hour, up to a full week!
> - Unstoppable - Cold Turkey can't be stopped easily as it is not stoppable from the system tray or the task manager.
> - Open Source - In addition to being free and charitable, the source code is available for everyone to see!

[image: Cold Turkey screenshot]